# Creating a Permission Validation using Builder Pattern with Dynamic Method Selection

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to create a TypeScript function that validates permissions using a builder pattern, and everything is functioning correctly except for the type definitions.

The usage would resemble the example below:

```js
const { can, message } = await authUser("2").can("EDIT").post("1");
```

I'm aiming to return specific methods based on the action provided as an argument in the "can" function. For instance, if the action is "BLOCK," I want it to only return the method `user(id)`.

Here's an example:

```js
// For "BLOCK," only the method "user(id)" should be returned
const { can, message } = await authUser("2").can("BLOCK").posts();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQEQCEAyA8gMIDS2UAPjgKIAiAkgCoXXbEBKNMTN2A3AChQkKBwgBnZAFcATnGhZs0iRFmscYZBOAbsWnRIGDBiVMDUAzAIYKoxa6nETpAG2BQA3oKi+ocRwAuKAAjZGRXCEchPygAW0kJawBzCGCdWTNkoQBfExFoAFkIYGQAE2RMKAAKRDKAfnTgTNRkgEpMAD4oAAVZZDjEVQAeBydJN2BOoUFrCRBUOChLaUWkNH9M61ke8ohnSeqAOhPt5IlggG0MrIAaWAQUVHub1vqAXTbgvoGhiFHHAd3N1vLE4GgpJEjq5kMlqmcJG0fH5ZCU5OhQbE-AFUMFmtIILdkVj4okUmkcC44AoJEYibEcrkTCs1k8oNZpMAABYAVVUsmqpQA1hBUHy1Awyk0Wu0vMSoKjgOi5STfDjgvDHmhgvB1qgOhgQfLVf4IR4EtzyhcxBBwbIysNnDJ5ISoMVShVulhMSaSSo1ME5gsltUwP1LIhIpKDSCFWjZOg4FsdnsgcBBcgRWL+ZL7rY9fcw8gI1Gyh0cvTfSSDMBA-NFjUa9Gul440qE5tENtdmV9hN3Bms+LZLn2VrnlAm2WoBXjVXJ9pgNagw3qjHW4rlUmuyne2nB6Lh6P809y5Wq4yTPO28qLVyrTFVbOGUzBPD6yH1z6oAB6H9QcV-DmCArz8awAHdrEQDwOW5YdqmwABGbA2iOHEEM4bheBQo4awkNd+F-f9CFIKAAFooAKCQoHA5BZCFLJQN8CCoJgzleX5BCACYcPQ7B6GYHCawQ5C2kIv8oBI8jKPASQaLohjWiY9lIOg9l2Pg7AeNQviCBIchUP9AUkJQ8TiNIiiqPk+jGOUli1Ngji1BE3jHAwrgeD4QzOLEoioAAMRgBh8Gkoy12WVZxygCo5NQZAPAgAAPIYlxorlRRwTDPIoE8NmQMA9Ts1S2LgzitNc1AEIElhUOEn8ACocGQqB6vqn8OgkwLgukhEFx0SV4hUDwQmgVEAEdpEQVEyiK1j1NK5zyp0ty8CIMghMXfCOv-LqQoomLqLihLksMPql3ClkorMHA9PWsc9SgfLCvleySqc4ztLQlbboMo4woapqKFa9q-N2nrZHOKAjIGuIhtCUaIAmqaIBmwQcjaNdBCAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does anyone have any other better options than this?

```js
interface CanResult {
    can: boolean;
    message: string;
}

type Method<T> = (id: T extends string ? string : void) => Promise<CanResult>;

async function buildResult(...args: [userId:string, resourceId?:string]): Promise<CanResult> {
    // logic to validate permission goes here
    return {
        can: true,
        message: "success",
    };
}

interface AuthUser {
    canBlock: () => Record<"user", Method<string>>;
    canEdit: () => Record<"user" | "post", Method<string>>;
    canDelete: () => Record<"user" | "post", Method<string>>;
    canList: () => Record<"posts" | "users", Method<void>>;
}

function authUser(tokenUserId: string): AuthUser {
    return {
        canBlock: () => {
            const methods: Record<"user", Method<string>> = {
                user: async (profileId) => buildResult(tokenUserId, profileId)
            };
            return methods;
        },
        canList: () => {
            const methods: Record<"posts" | "users", Method<void>> = {
                users: async () => buildResult(tokenUserId),
                posts: async () => buildResult(tokenUserId)
            };
            return methods;
        },
        canEdit: () => {
            const methods: Record<"user" | "post", Method<string>> = {
                user: async (profileId) => buildResult(tokenUserId, profileId),
                post: async (postId) => buildResult(tokenUserId, postId)
            };
            return methods;
        },
        canDelete: () => {
            const methods: Record<"user" | "post", Method<string>> = {
                user: async (profileId) => buildResult(tokenUserId, profileId),
                post: async (postId) => buildResult(tokenUserId, postId)
            };
            return methods;
        },
    };
}

(async () => {
    // Use case

    await authUser("1").canBlock().user("2"); // OK - types working

    await authUser("2").canEdit().post("2"); // OK - types working

    await authUser("1").canList().posts(); // OK - types working

    await authUser("1").canDelete().post("1"); // OK - types working

})()
```